# WPF Control Freeze after WindowsFormsHost trigger to view PDF

Tags: wpf, pdf, windowsformshost, axacropdf

I'm having problem with my User Control freeze. It's happen when I'm triggering the WindowsFormsHost to preview the PDF File. The pdf file still running in the WindowsFormsHost where i can still scroll to view it. However, my other controls(togglebutton,popupbox,etc) doesn't seems to work.

Here is the XAML code for WindowsFormsHost in my UserControl

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,203,0">
  <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="ViewPDFWinForm" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="444" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="708"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code to trigger the WindowsFormsHost to call PDF File from UserControl

```
PreviewReportPDF uc = new PreviewReportPDF(ReportGenerator.ReportPath);
this.ViewPDFWinForm.Child = uc;
```

Here is how I pass the pdf file path

```
public PreviewReportPDF(string filepath)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filepath);
        this.axAcroPDF1.setZoom(63);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed your example, as good as I could. I cannot see why you controls are freezing.
It seems that the issue is located anywhere else.

I added the Acrobat Reader Control to a UserControl "UserControl1"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApplication9
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public UserControl1(string filepath)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filepath);
        this.axAcroPDF1.setZoom(63);
    }
}
}
```

I created a WPF Window, like this:

```
Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host"/>
    <ToggleButton Content="Toggle" Grid.Column="1" Click="ToggleButton_Click" />

</Grid>
</Window>
```

and with this code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace WpfApplication9
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1(System.IO.Path.Combine(Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "Test.pdf"));
        this.host.Child = uc;
    }

    private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hallo welt!");
    }
}
}
```

After the pdf file was loaded I could fire the Toggle Button Event, so Messagebox was shown. This is the reason why I gues your issue Comes from anywhere else.

Comment: I have done this example before I post this question here. If it is just this code alone, i can run the program. But, when I try to combine with my main program, the controls like i state in the question freeze without throw any error. I guess I will keep looking where the mistake is. BTW, thanks for the example tho. It might help others. I will share the solution here when I solved it later.